# Can I use GPUDirect v2 Peer-to-Peer communication between two Quadro K1100M or two GeForce GT 745M?

Tags: cuda, nvidia, gpgpu, gpudirect

Can I use [GPUDirect v2 - Peer-to-Peer communication](https://developer.nvidia.com/gpudirect) on a single PCIe-Bus?:

- between two: Mobile nVidia Quadro K1100M
- between two: Mobile nVidia GeForce GT 745M

Comment: How did you put two mobile GPUs on a single bus?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In general, if you want to find out if GPUDirect Peer to Peer is supported between two GPUs,  you can run the [simple P2P CUDA sample code](http://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-samples/index.html#simple-peer-to-peer-transfers-with-multi-gpu) or in your own code, you can test the availability with the [cudaCanAccessPeer runtime API call](http://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-runtime-api/group__CUDART__PEER.html#group__CUDART__PEER)

Note that in general, P2P support may vary by GPU or GPU family.  The ability to run P2P on one GPU type or GPU family does not necessarily indicate it will work on another GPU type or family, even in the same system/setup.  The final determinant of GPU P2P support are the tools provided that query the runtime via `cudaDeviceCanAccessPeer`.    P2P support can vary by system and other factors as well.  No statements made here are a guarantee of P2P support for any particular GPU in any particular setup.

Comment: Thank you. Are there in nVidia a list (table) of all graphics cards with marks/notes of various characteristics, something similar to http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_Nvidia_graphics_processing_units, but more detailed?

Comment: I'm not aware of any.